# Unable to access library files from controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have created a new library file `sampler.rb` inside the lib folder. Consider this as the content of the file

```
module Sampler
    def sample_tester
        "test"
    end
end
```

I have included it in the application_controller and added a require statement in the `config\initializers`. When I try to access the method sample_tester from my controllers, I get the following error

```
undefined local variable or method `sample_tester` for #<BlogsController:0xb8fbac8>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: do you need to define it as a class method instead?  self.sample_tester ?

Comment: add the code of the initializer and the part of your controller where you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't look like you are creating an instance of this, my first guess is that you need to define it as a class method so that it can be called like this: `Sampler.sample_tester`.

In your file you could do it one of two ways:

```
# first way
module Sampler
  def self.sample_tester
    "test"
  end
end

# second way
module Sampler
  class << self
    def sample_tester
      "test"
    end
end
```

The second way is nicer if you want to define a number of class methods.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have your module method defined as a class method you need to use extend instead of include:

```
module Mod
  def bla
    puts "bla"
  end
end

class String
  include Mod
end

String.bla rescue puts $! # => undefined method `bla' for String:Class

class String
  extend Mod
end

puts String.bla # => bla
```

Comment: Is there any link explaining how exactly library files(files inside /lib folder) can be used in rails?

Comment: they can be used like any other ruby file. if you add the lib folder to the autoload-path then rails will automatically reload them on each request. if you put stuf in the initializer, this will only be reloaded on initialization http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html